# how to ask VIM to do operations before executing standard command

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

When I use the ":w" command to save the file I'm editing, i wish to execute some operation before (i.e. compare the original file with another).

It's possibile to do this? with a plugin? with a script?

Comment: Start [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html), write as much code as you can figure out (in your .vimrc), and come back when you get stuck.

Comment: Well Kevin, I try to find time to read all :-) - Andrea